# Java Class reference data type

Tags: java

```
public class Name{
    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;
}
public class Info{
    public Name name;
    public int age;
}
public class test{
public static void main(String[] args){
   Info v = new Info();
   v.age=12;
   System.out.println();
 }
}
```

I am trying to create a object v with age, firstname and lastname in test class. I have initialised age as v.age =12, but how can I initialize firstname and lastname in test class?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could do this.  This:

```
v.name = new Name();
v.name.firstname = "John";
v.name.lastname = "Smith";
```

Or this:

```
Name n = new Name();
n.firstname = "John";
n.lastname = "Smith";
v.name = n;
```

Comment: I just realized that my first example assumes `name` is initialized, which it isn't.

Comment: It's not working. I tried to print v.name.firstname. Error I get is "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at test.main"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  Info v = new Info();
  v.age=12;
  v.name = new Name();
  v.name.firstname = "Joe";
  v.name.lastname = "Smith";
  System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: It will work if we remove 7th line that is   v.name = name;

Answer (score 0):

The age and name fields should not be public variables. They should be private, and should be set via parameters to the constructor. Then you would have getters to retrieve their values, and setters which would allow the values to be set only in controlled circumstances. For example,

```
public class Info{
   private Name name;
   private int age;

   public Info( String firstname, String lastname, int a ) {
      age = a;
      name = new Name(firstname, lastname);
   }

   public Info( Name n, int a ) {
      age = a;
      name = n;
   }

   int getAge() {
      return age;
   }

   Name getName() {
      return name;
   }
}
```

then your main() would create Info instances in one of 2 ways:

```
   Info info = new Info("Joe", "Smith", 12 );

   Name name = new Name("Bill", "Smith");
   Info info2 = new Info( name, );
```